# Sum of textboxes in yii2 dynamic form

Tags: javascript, yii2

I'm trying to get sum of all the "Price" textboxes in another textbox "Amount".
The textbox for price is ssgi_price and the textbox for Amount is ssg_amount.
The intention is whenever I put some value in the Price Textbox, the sum of all price textboxes should populate in the Amount textbox.

Like below image - [image]

Code of my _form looks like -

```
<div class="container-items"><!-- widgetContainer -->
            <?php foreach ($modelsSellitemsg as $i => $modelSellitemsg): ?>
                <div class="item panel panel-default"><!-- widgetBody -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (! $modelSellitemsg->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelSellitemsg, "[{$i}]id");
                            }
                        ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <?= $form->field($modelSellitemsg, "[{$i}]ssgi_sgname")->label(false)->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Sunglass::find()->all(),'sg_name','sg_name'),
                                    'language' => 'en',
                                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Sunglass'],
                                    'pluginOptions' => [
                                        'allowClear' => true
                                    ],
                                    ]); 
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <?= $form->field($modelSellitemsg, "[{$i}]ssgi_price")->textInput([
                                'maxlength' => true,
                                'onfocus'=>'sum()', 'onBlur'=>'sum()']) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- .row -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'ssg_amount')->textInput() ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the Javascript I'm trying -

```
<?php
/* start getting the totalamount */
$script = <<<EOD
  $(function sum(){
    id = 0;
    suma = 0;
    existe = true;
    while(existe){
        var idFull = "#sellsg-"+id+"-ssgi_price";
        try{campo = document.getElementById(idFull);
            if(document.getElementById(idFull).value!=''){
            suma = suma + parseInt(document.getElementById(idFull).value);
            }
            id = id+1;
        }catch(e){
            existe = false;
        }
        $('#sellsg-ssg_amount').val(suma);
    }
  });
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
/*end getting the totalamount */
?>
```

The error I'm getting - 
[image]

After Implementing Kostas's Solution

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

First give a CSS class to your inputs:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <?= $form->field($modelSellitemsg, "[{$i}]ssgi_price")->textInput([
    'maxlength' => true,
    'class' => 'sumPart']) ?>
</div>
```

and

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ssg_amount')->textInput(['class' => 'sum']) ?>
```

Then register the following jQuery:

```
<?php
/* start getting the totalamount */
$script = <<<EOD
    var getSum = function() {

        var items = $(".item");
        var sum = 0;

        items.each(function (index, elem) {
            var priceValue = $(elem).find(".sumPart").val();
            //Check if priceValue is numeric or something like that
            sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(priceValue);
        });
        //Assign the sum value to the field
        $(".sum").val(sum);
    };

    //Bind new elements to support the function too
    $(".container-items").on("change", ".sumPart", function() {
        getSum();
    });
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
/*end getting the totalamount */
?>
```

Comment: Hi Kostas, I've tried your solution. I think something is wrong. I've updated the present output in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Yes, you need to cast value as integer. Try the updated answer and it will work.

Comment: If you want float round you can use the following function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round