# Add class to bootstrap textbox - yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a form in yii2. In that I have a input field like below.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="productsales-<?= $i ?>-value">
```

It's inside a dynamic form andno coming from any model.It's just to hold some calculated value. And the idea is to calculate the values fileed by users in this field to another textbox like below -

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'sum']) ?>
```

I already have the javascript code to calculate the total amount like below -

```
<?php
/* start getting the total amount */
$script = <<<EOD
    var getSum = function() {

        var items = $(".item");
        var sum = 0;

        items.each(function (index, elem) {
            var priceValue = $(elem).find(".sumPart").val();
            //Check if priceValue is numeric or something like that
            sum = (parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(priceValue)).toFixed(2);
        });
        //Assign the sum value to the field
        $(".sum").val(sum);
    };

    //Bind new elements to support the function too
    $(".container-items").on("change", ".sumPart", function() {
        getSum();
    });
EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
/*end getting the total amount */
?>
```

Please note that I have a class `sum` in the second textbox which comes from a model. My question is that how can I add a class(`sumPart`) like this(`sum`) in the first textbox which is not coming from a model.

**Update after discussion with Insane Skull**

I have a dynamic form like below
[image]
I want to calculate sum of all the entries in Value and pass it to amount.

The code of Value is -

```
<input type="text" class="form-control sumPart" id="productsales-<?= $i ?>-value">
```

The code of Amount is -

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'sum']) ?>
```

The javascript I've tried is already given above.
The problem with this code is the calculated "value" is not passing to amount textbox.

**Update: A little issue**
[image]

Comment: you want to add class `sumPart` to normal html field? Using js or normally?

Comment: If that can be added  as the other tixtbox(that is coming from the model) that will be good.

Comment: I don't get it. You can always add public fields in model and use it anywhere.

Comment: I want to add sumPart class to <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productsales-<?= $i ?>-value">

Comment: Using js? or any other way. Still unclear buddy.

Comment: Brother my intention is to calculate the values in the plain textboxes in the dynamic form to a inputfield outside of dynamic form. And the calculation is done by JS. So, if I can assign the class by JS and get the calculated value as stated above by the JS code I've posted above then JS please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128142/discussion-between-insane-skull-and-tanmay).

Comment: I've updated the question as discussed.

Comment: Is the javascript part to be changed or the textbox? This javascript works fine with a textbox that comes from a model.

Comment: Is your amount textbox outside dynamic form? Which fields value you want to total and display in amount?

Comment: Yes. It is outside the dynamic form.

Comment: Which fields you want to calculate or JS is ok. Need to pass value?

Comment: Calculate sum of value and pass it to amount.

Comment: For each value textbox? Is your js working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187423/sum-of-textboxes-in-yii2-dynamic-form - Please have a look at this. This one is working perfectly. The difference between this link and my current question is in the example the "price" textbox is coming from a model. But in current question the "value" textbox is not coming from a model. Otherwise the JS works fine.

Comment: JS is working. but not taking value from "value" textbox.

Comment: Ok..will make a demo, when get time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify JS :

```
$this->registerJs('
    function getSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        var items = $(".item");
        items.each(function (index, elem) {
            var priceValue = $(elem).find(".sumPart").val();
            sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(priceValue);
        });

       if(isNaN(sum) || sum.length == 0) {
           sum = 0;
       }
       $(".sum").val(sum);
    }

    $(".container-items").on("change", function() {
        getSum();
    });

    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
        getSum();
    }); 
');
```

Comment: It is working. Except there is a small issue. Say I click on the + button add a new row. When there is a new value it is adding up to amount. But if I remove the new row or any other previous row, then the amount is not changing. I've added a screen print of it in the question.

Comment: Thanks. Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I am little unsure about the problem you are facing. If you want to add a class to a input field, you can easily do so in the `class` attribute of the input tag. And the `class` attribute does support multiple values, so you can write something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control sumPart" id="productsales-<?= $i ?>-value">
```

**UPDATE -- based on comment by OP **

@Tanmay, I understand that you may not be getting the desired output. However, it should not really matter if we are rendering the fields using `$form->field()` or plain HTML. If the fields have the proper classes assigned, then the JS code posted by Kostas in your referenced link should work - irrespective of how the class name was added to the input field.

Can you please confirm (by using Inspect Element) if the sumPart class is actually assigned to the relevant fields once the page loads? Maybe some JS is overwriting the class attribute again?

If the classes are assigned properly, please check if there are any other JS errors in console which may prevent the sum calculation JS from working properly.

Comment: it's not giving the desired output. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187423/sum-of-textboxes-in-yii2-dynamic-form. What I want is to calculate sum of the textboxes inside the dynamic form and put the result in an outside box. In the link given, the dynamic form fields are coming from a model. But in my present question, the textbox that we are adding sumPart is not coming from any model. The textbox works fine, but I have to add class sumPart to it like in the link given.